# Always the function getInvitationId() is null in the callback onSignInSucceeded()

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am working with 2 real devices, and I can do signing successful and the onSignInSucceeded()  call back is called normally.   When I sent a invitation from A to B and the game in device B is not gamming, then the notification arrive without problems. However, if the player B accept the invitation, then when the game in B calls  to onSignInSucceeded()  there is not invitationId available,  it is that  getInvitationId() is null.

I was checking onConnected() code and saw that the Bundle connectionHint is not null, however,  when it try to recovery the invitation with.

Invitation inv = connectionHint.getParcelable(GamesClient.EXTRA_INVITATION);

That returns null, therefore if inv is null then getting  the invitationId is not initialized.

Everyone knows more about these issues?

Answer (score 0):

The  old  GameHelper  works  GameClient  it  is  deprecate..   the  problem   was  solve  for  using  new  GoogleApiClient.